# How to get Carbon time with format like that '2019-07-20T09:20:33+00:00' in PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-carbon

I want to get string of current time with format like **'`2019-07-20T09:20:33+00:00`'** using Carbon.

 
Currently I'm using **`Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();`** -->

```
output: 2019-07-20 21:02:48
```

What is name of this format time **`2019-07-20T09:20:33+00:00`** ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Date format is ISO 8601.

Code sample is `date('c')`.